# when using stdout, why changing to file object needed?

Tags: python, stdout

Below is the example of using stdout module.

```
#redirect.py

import sys

f = open('t.txt', 'w')        
stdout = sys.stdout   -----> first one
sys.stdout = f        -----> second one
print 'Sample output'
print 'Good'
print 'Good'
f.close()
sys.stdout = stdout   -----> third one
```

I could not understand why meaning of those three things above.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` simply massages its arguments and then invokes `sys.stdout.write()`. Replacing `sys.stdout` allows you to capture the output of `print` and redirect it.

Comment: could you explain the first one and third one ??

Comment: Um, saving and restoring the original value.

Comment: Sorry but could u explain in detail? I wonder why saving and restoring the sys.stdout and what is the original value in this context? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: i just want the meaning of original value which you have mentioned above

Comment: The original sys.stdout points to the terminal you are executing python from, the output label of the gui you are using, what you would expect to see print print to. The first one stores the original, default output terminal, gui label, etc. The second makes print write to the file t.txt. The third makes print look back to the the default file, terminal, etc.